# Cookies on Android

Tags: android, codenameone

I've written an application that logins to a server and accepts cookies as session id for future requests. All works fine in j2me but not on android devices. On Android the application doesn't add the cookie in the body of request. I've tested in simulator and checked the network monitor all works fine but I don't know why it doesn't on real device.
Wanted to parse and add cookie myself with but Util.getImplementation() is can not be accessed out of its package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the code I think there is a bug in the Android implementation, feel free to file an issue in the Codename One issue tracker. Thanks.